# How to show this identity is true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^{\Omega (k)}}{k^{s}}\right)^{2}=\frac{\zeta (4s)}{\zeta (2s)}\frac{2^{s-1}}{i-2^{s-1}}$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\Omega (k)$ is the number of (not necessarily distinct) prime divisors of $k$. (For example $\Omega (12)=\Omega (2^{2}.3^{1})=2+1=3$.

Is this identity true? How to prove it?

Comment: If you let $s \to +\infty$ through real values, the left hand side tends to $1$, and the right to $-1$. Perhaps a sign error somewhere?